# I couldnt update the variable that in the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I want to update variable that in array. Like `katsayi_adam` etc. but I couldn't change the variable.

```
control = []
CezaSayac = 0
i=0 
katsayi_adam = 1
katsayi_nadam = 1
katsayi_adamax = 1
katsayilar = [katsayi_adam,katsayi_nadam,katsayi_adamax]
a=0
for i in range(3):
    if(1==1):
        control.append(1)
        CezaSayac += 1
    else:
        control.append(0)
for a in range(3):
    if control[a] == 1:
        katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a] + 1/67
    else:
        katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a]- ((CezaSayac)/67)/(67-CezaSayac)
print(control)
print(katsayi_adam)
print(katsayi_nadam)
print(katsayi_adamax)
```

output always like this:

```
[1, 1, 1]

1

1

1
```

Comment: Now, which variable exactly? What is the error precisely?  What is the desired output?

Comment: `if(1==1)` is always true, so it will add 1s every time. Maybe you need something else?

Comment: i did that for i just wanna see the variable it turns 3 time and control array inside is [1,1,1] after that going second for checking inside control [a] it should add 1/67 for 3 time to the katsayi_adam but output is saying katsayi_adam = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`katsayilar` is a list of premative elements (int) which are passed by value and not by reference. So when you are updating `katsayilar` you only update the list elements and not the elements you assigned to it when you creating the list, i.e. you are not updating `katsayi_adam, katsayi_nadam, katsayi_adamax`.

**Edit** - assign the list to the variables after the calculation

```
control = []
CezaSayac = 0
i=0 
katsayi_adam = 1
katsayi_nadam = 1
katsayi_adamax = 1
katsayilar = [katsayi_adam,katsayi_nadam,katsayi_adamax]
a=0
for i in range(3):
    if(1==1):
        control.append(1)
        CezaSayac += 1
    else:
        control.append(0)

for a in range(3):
    if control[a] == 1:
        katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a] + 1/67
    else:
        katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a]- ((CezaSayac)/67)/(67-CezaSayac)
print(control)
print(katsayi_adam)
print(katsayi_nadam)
print(katsayi_adamax)
katsayi_adam,katsayi_nadam,katsayi_adamax = katsayilar
print(katsayi_adam)
print(katsayi_nadam)
print(katsayi_adamax)
```

Output -

```
[1, 1, 1]
1
1
1
1.0149253731343284
1.0149253731343284
1.0149253731343284
```

Comment: thank youuuuuu katsayi_adam,katsayi_nadam,katsayi_adamax = katsayilar it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you want but i have find a mistake in it and i have mentioned it. if you want more information regarding your query then tell me what you want from your script in detail

```
control = []
CezaSayac = 0
i=0 
katsayi_adam = 1
katsayi_nadam = 1
katsayi_adamax = 1
katsayilar = [katsayi_adam,katsayi_nadam,katsayi_adamax]
a=0
for i in range(3):
    if(i==1):  # use i instead of one..if(i==1):
        control.append(1)
        CezaSayac += 1
    else:
        control.append(0)
for a in range(3):
    if control[a] == 1:
        katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a] + 1/67
    else:
        katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a]- ((CezaSayac)/67)/(67-CezaSayac)
print(control)
print(katsayi_adam)
print(katsayi_nadam)
print(katsayi_adamax)
```

Comment: i just want to add 1/67 to variable that in control[a] i did that for i just wanna see the variable it turns 3 time and control array inside is [1,1,1] after that going second for checking inside control [a] it should add 1/67 for 3 time to the katsayi_adam but output is saying katsayi_adam = 1

Comment: control list contain only 1 or 0 according to the data of katsayi_adam = 1
katsayi_nadam = 1
katsayi_adamax = 1 ?

Comment: addition of 1/67 depends on CezaSayac and what CezaSayac variable contains numbers,is it number of 1's in control list?

Comment: if control[a] contains 0 then we should not update the value in katsayi_adam, is it right

Comment: and if control[a] contains 1 then add 1/67 CezaSayac times in katsayi_adam

Comment: that you want or something else

Comment: forget the cezasayac just the important thing is here :     if control[a] == 1:
        katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a] + 1/67

Comment: the control [a] will turn 3 time but the katsayilar[a] is not changing normaly every variable that in katsayilar[] array change for 1 time adding 1/67

Answer (score 0):

You need to set to either the numerator or the denominator to be of data type `float`.

So instead of:

```
katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a] + 1/67
```

it should be:

```
katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a] + float(1)/67
```

or

```
katsayilar[a] = katsayilar[a] + 1/float(67)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do have a typo in your first for loop code. Your code contains:

```
if (1==1):
```

means that the values of control are always [1,1,1].

So the first for loop is meaningless.

As for the second part. You are adding the values and then deleting them again. I presume you are doing this on purpose and that you always want to end up with [1,1,1] and that this is actually some sort of puzzle code! You are adding 1/67 and then deleting it again as part of your second loop.

Comment: so what should i do then ? it should keep adding 1/67 i want that i dont want to delete after add how can i do that the important thing second loop first loop is just a trash i change for i see

Comment: Well, you need to ask yourself then, why are you performing the second part of the second for loop. That part is a subtraction. If you say you want to keep adding 1/67 then why do you have any deletion part to the loop?